# Web setup (msi installer) and iis 7 (applicationhost.config)

Tags: visual-studio-2010, iis-7, web, windows-installer, installation

When i run my msi installer created through web setup of vs2010.
It install web application correctly but **

> configure physical path of application incorrectly.

**
any one has idea why this is happining
e.g it has extra forword slash as below

[image]

Comment: Physical Path look like  `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\YourAppFolderName`

Answer (score 0):

Try to create a [verbose log](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/223300) and post it if you can't find the problem in it by yourself.